# Filter choices of a combo box in powerapp for a single app

Tags: powerapps

Problem statement: Needing to filter out "Time" from a Choices('Reason Code') used in a combobox in PowerApp for a single app. This approach is needed due to concern of potentially affecting historical data if just removing the value "Time" from the list of choices instead or it impact on other apps that make use of this Choices('Reason Code')

Things tried: I posed the question to ChatGPT as I am not to familiar with PowerApps. This AI chatbot suggested using:

> //On App Start or appropriate event
> ClearCollect(FilterChoices, Filter(Choices(YourDataSource.ReasonCode), Value <> "Time"))
>
> //The set the Items property of your control to:
> FilterChoices

However, with what little knowledge of PowerApps and what I see present in the dialog boxes after trying item property and other fields I can't recall at the moment none of these seem to result in the desired end of simply removing the choice of Time.

Any suggestions or resources would be appreciated.

Comment: What I understood from your problem statement is that you don't want "Time" to show up in your combobox. Ryt?

Comment: Can you provide more details about your list/table and column types? Are you using date & time column or choice column? If choice column, can you show us the options you have for choice column (in column settings)?

Comment: Reply to Singh: Yes, for one of the apps we do not want "Time" to be seen by the user anymore and we think that simply removing it as an option from the Choices may affect historical data.

Comment: Reply to Sanap: I do not have the details of the table. The list defined in the Choices() is several options with "Time being one of them however we do not want to simply remove "Time" as an option but instead researching option into filtering out this option within the application that utilizes this Choices() for the ComboBox.

Comment: To add to Sanap: Looks like its a single column table called Reason Code so the function looks like described above as Choices('Reason Code') and is being used to in a ComboBox to provide a dropdown of these reason codes with Time being one of the codes.